# Dropbox Chooser API

Tags: dropbox-api

I have followed the entire dropbox chooser documentation, and have the code implemented in the page, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the file automatically download after it has been selected, I cannot find any working Javascript functions to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // add an event listener to a Chooser button
    document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
        function(e) {
            alert("Here's the chosen file: " + e.files[0].link)
        }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @phyrrus9 <input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // add an event listener to a Chooser button
    document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
        function(e) {
            alert("Here's the chosen file: " + e.files[0].link)
        }, false);
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `window.location = e.files[0].link`?

But it seems odd to have the user choose a file in his/her own Dropbox and then download the file. I'm curious why you're doing this.

Comment: Just descided to cheat a bit to have a "Web file manager" for the pta that needed a site